# Undo mark for add in Perforce (p4v)

Tags: perforce

I accidentally marked for add some files that already existed in the codebase and now they appear as additions. When I submit via SmartBear Codecollab, the diffs show that it is a completely new file when really I only edited a few lines.

Is there a better way to get around this than saving a copy of the file locally, reverting through p4, and then checking out the file again?

Comment: You can (slightly) simplify the process by using `p4 revert -k` and `p4 edit -k` to change your open state from 'open for add' to 'open for edit', without having to save a copy of your edited copy somewhere else. Sticking `-k` on those two commands tells the server to update its metadata about what you're doing without making any changes to your copy of the file.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. Do you know if p4v has this functionality too?

Comment: Another command line solution to accidental `p4 add FILE` is `p4 revert FILE` (no editing needed).  I don't use p4v or I'd actually create an answer here.